# Expectancy of a joint density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A machine consists of two components, whose life times have the joint density function

$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1/50, & \text{for }x>0,y>0,x+y<10 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

The machine operates until both components fail.
Calculate the expected operational time of the machine.

With the boundaries I have found the vertices at (0,0) , (10,0) and (0,10) but I dont have the idea how to continue it seems like the answer is just 5. Hope anyone can give me a hand on this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For given $x,y>0$, the lifetime of the machine is $\max\{x,y\}$ because it stops when the two components fail. The life expectancy if therefore the expectancy of $\max\{x,y\}$ 
$$t=\mathbb{E}\left[\max\{x,y\}\right]=
\iint \max\{x,y\}f(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$
At this moment you may want to draw a small graph:

[image]

(I have edited the end of the answer.)

In the white triangles we have $\max\{x,y\}=x$, and in the gray triangle  $\max\{x,y\}=y$. To compute the integral, it is useful to divide the domain into subdomains.

The integral on the grey triangle is 
$$I_1=\frac1{50}\int_0^5\mathrm dx\int_x^{10-x}y\mathrm dy=\frac{1}{50}\int_0^5\frac12\left((100-x)^2-x^2\right)\mathrm dx=\frac52.$$

The integral on the first white triangle is
$$I_2=\frac1{50}\int_0^5\mathrm dx\int_0^xx\mathrm dy=\frac56.$$

The third integral is 
$$I_3=\frac{1}{50}\int_5^{10}\mathrm dx\int_0^{10-x}x\mathrm dy=\frac53.$$

So the total is $I_1+I_2+I_3=5$. Note that by symmetry you have $I_1=I_2+I_3$ which makes the computation much easier.

Comment: i wonder how you get the triangles? why are there x triangles and y triangles?

Comment: The line $y=x$ determines whether $\max\{x,y\}=x$ (white triangles) or $\max\{x,y\}=y$ (grey triangles). The line $y=10-x$ is the line you have found for the domain where $f(x,y)\neq0$. The dasehd line correspond to the way one should cut the triangles to perform the integral.

Comment: Can you explain the bounds to me. Why does I1 have bounds x,10-x for y. Shouldn't it be  x, 10?

Comment: @pasha. No, this is correct. We are integrating over the gray triangle, which is delimited by three lines $D_1:x=0$, $D_2:y=x$ and $D_3:x+y=10$. In the formula, I integrate first over $x$, which is fixed in the integral over $y$. The vertical line at absciss $x$ crosses the triangle's sides $D_2$ at the point $(x,x)$ and $D_3$ at the point $(x, 10-x)$.